# Portrait/Landscape iPad laying out views

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I've got redesign for couple of screens on iPad. I gave a lot of thought and can't pick the best solution (or better) for laying out views. Screens are portrait and landscape orientation. 4 views should be layed out in a row if it's in landscape and 2 by 2 if they are in portrait.

[image]
[image]

I wanted to hear your opinion how would you takle this:

1) all on storyboard

2) part in storyboard part in code

3) all in code (I think this is simplest solution, but adds more (plausibly) unneeded code)

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be a collection with flow layout , and change it's height according to the current orientation that fits for 2 items (in height) in portrait and one item in landscape by adjusting itemSize

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these are Collection Views, I would create two subclasses of UICollectionViewLayout: one for portrait, and one for landscape. [Here's a handy tutorial for doing so by Ray Wenderlich.](https://www.raywenderlich.com/164608/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest-2) If you're not using a Collection View, I recommend it if your views are similar to each other.